# add an array of string in query nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to make sure of these two lines `(antecedants:[req.query.antecedants] +info.antecedants.push([req.query.antecedants])`
as it shown from the code antecedents is an array of string so in my query I want to add an array of string but when I called this method(`infopatient`) it adds all the values except the array(empty).

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
//define schema
var Schema= mongoose.Schema;
var ficheSchema= Schema({
  Datevisite: Date,
  Age:Number ,
  Pouls : Number ,
  TA : Number ,
  temperature : Number ,
  FR : Number,
  SAO2 : Number ,
  CGS : Number,
  antecedants : [String] ,
  motif :  String ,
  EVA:Number,
  id_patient : String
})



var fiche = mongoose.model('fiche',ficheSchema);
module.exports= fiche ;
//
app.get("/infopatient", (req, res) =>{
    var info = new fiches ( {
        Age:req.query.Age,
         Pouls : req.query.Pouls,
        TA:req.query.TA,
        temperature:req.query.temperature,
      FR:req.query.FR,
      SAO2:req.query.SAO2,
      CGS:req.query.CGS,
      EVA:req.query.EVA ,
      antecedants:[req.query.antecedants],
      Tmotif:req.query.motif}
      );
     info.antecedants.push([req.query.antecedants])
     info.save(function(err)
     {
        if(err) return handleError(err);
    });          
  })
```

Comment: When you do `info.antecedants.push([req.query.antecedants])`, I don't believe this is a valid type in your schema because `info.antecedants` is already an array, and you're adding a nested array into the data model.

Comment: Thank you but i know that the problem is in that line (push) and i don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: Just wondering, why are you pushing to it when you set upon declaring `new fiches`? Alternatively have you tried `info.antecedants.push(req.query.antecedants)` ?

Comment: Actualy  this method get("/infopatient") is called in my android project ,  and the application shows a form which the user should put the values to create a new fiche  , when i deleted the line of info.antecedants.push(req.query.antecedants) this field is showed empty in the database and when i add it ,the column antecendents appear but the value is empty . Ps : the other attributes are successfully added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines `antecedants:[req.query.antecedants]` and `info.antecedants.push([req.query.antecedants])` seem redundant to me. You should only need the first one for this to work. You would only need to use `push` if you were updating an existing object.

If you're not seeing your `antecedants` array being populated I would suggest you make sure your `req.query.antecedants` is defined.

But also `antecedants:[req.query.antecedants]` seems brittle. The naming suggests that multiple string values can be passed in to `antecedants` here. Is it comma separated? If so, you might want something like this for example:

```
antecedants: req.query.antecedants ? req.query.antecedants.split(',') : []
```

If its not comma separated, you could instead simply do this:

```
antecedants: req.query.antecedants ? [req.query.antecedants] : []
```